# Windows 10: fopen, fread, fgets and mixed EOL characters in large text file

Tags: c, windows, fopen, fgets, fread

I am developing a program for computational material scientists:

https://atomes.ipcms.fr/

Atomes can import large text files that contains atomic coordinates,
to do that I read the file as a whole using `fread`,
then split the text buffer over the CPU cores using OpenMP.

Works wonder on Linux, and Windows, until someone came along with an issue I wasn't expecting. A file with mixed, and not regularly placed, EOL symbols (`\n` and `\r`).

I found a way to overcome the problem on Windows, and Windows only,
and I would really appreciate your advise/comment on what I did to know if I used a proper correction.

Before that solution I tried to add option(s) to the `fopen` function like `-t` or `-b` but it had no effect.

Finally I noticed that there was no problem if I change compilation options and use the `fgets` function to read the data from the file, only in that case and for large files the treatment of the data is more complicated, so far I no way // using OpenMP, and takes more time.

Here is the code I wrote to read the file:

```
int open_coord_file (gchar * filename)
{
  int res;
#ifdef OPENMP
  // In that case I read the file in a single buffer, then work on that buffer
  struct stat status;
  res = stat (filename, & status);
  if (res == -1)
  {
    // Basic function to store information on the reading process
    add_reader_info ("Error - cannot get file statistics !");
    return 1;
  }
  int fsize = status.st_size;
#endif
  coordf = fopen (filename, "r");
  if (! coordf)
  {
    add_reader_info ("Error - cannot open coordinates file !");
    return 1;
  }
  int i, j, k;
#ifdef OPENMP
  gchar * coord_content = g_malloc0(fsize*sizeof*coord_content);
  // Using fread to read the entire file
  fread (coord_content, fsize, 1, coordf);
  fclose (coordf);
  int linecount = 0;
  // Evaluating the number of lines in the file:
  for (j=0; j<fsize; j++) if (coord_content[j] == '\n') linecount ++;
#ifdef G_OS_WIN32
  // What happen in Windows is that some '\r' symbols were found
  // and not on all lines, so I decided to check for \r symbols: 
  int neolr = 0;
  for (j=0; j<fsize; j++) if (coord_content[j] == '\r') neolr ++;
  // And mofidy the number of lines accordingly
  linecount -= neolr;
#endif
  coord_line = g_malloc0 (linecount*sizeof*coord_line);
  coord_line[0] = & coord_content[0];
  i = 1;
  int nfsize = fsize;
#ifdef G_OS_WIN32
  // Now deleting the corresponding EOL symbols in the text buffer
  // This is only required for Windows, and I am not sure that it is 
  // the proper way to do thing, any though on the matter would be appreciated.
  for (j=0; j<fsize; j++)
  {
    if (coord_content[j] == '\n')
    {
      coord_content[j] = '\0';
    }
    else if (coord_content[j] == '\r')
    {
      for (k=j; k<fsize-1; k++)
      {
        coord_content[k] = coord_content[k+1];
      }
      nfsize --;
    }
  }
#endif
  // And referencing properly the lines to work on the buffer:
  for (j=0; j<nfsize; j++)
  {
    if (coord_content[j] == '\0')
    {
      if (i < linecount)
      {
        coord_line[i] = & coord_content[j+1];
        i++;
      }
    }
  }
#else
  // On the other side if turn down OpenMP, then I use the fgets function
  // to read the data from the text file, then there no problem what so ever
  // with the EOL symbols and everything work smoothly. 
  // The fopen options being the same I am somewhat confused by this result. 
  gchar * buf = g_malloc0(LINE_SIZE*sizeof*buf);
  struct line_node
  {
    gchar * line;//[LINE_SIZE];
    struct line_node * next;
    struct line_node * prev;
  };
  struct line_node * head = NULL;
  struct line_node * tail = NULL;
  i = 0;
  while (fgets(buf, LINE_SIZE, coordf))
  {
    if (head == NULL)
    {
      head = g_malloc0 (sizeof*head);
      tail = g_malloc0 (sizeof*tail);
      tail = head;
    }
    else
    {
      tail -> next = g_malloc0 (sizeof*tail -> next);
      tail = tail -> next;
    }
    tail -> line = g_strdup_printf ("%s", buf);
    tail -> line = substitute_string (tail -> line, "\n", "\0");
    i ++;
  }
  g_free (buf);
  fclose (coordf);
#endif 

// And then latter in the code I process the data
// providing i the number of lines as an input value.

return read_xyz_file (i);
```

Any advise would be really appreciated.

[EDIT]

I found a way arround my `fread`issue using a temporary buffer with `fgets` so I could get my data // with OpenMP easily again:

```
coord_line = g_malloc0 (i*sizeof*coord_line);
tail = head;
j = 0;
while (tail)
{
  coord_line[j] = & tail -> line[0];
  j ++;
  tail = tail -> next;
}
```

Now everything is fine, though I still have no clues why I am having issues with `fread`

[/EDIT]

Comment: `tail = g_malloc0 (sizeof*tail);` followed immediately by `tail = head;`... Memory leak at a minimum...

Comment: Simple question: Do you want an array of 'n' pointers to null terminated strings, each string 'cleansed' of any '\r', but separated by '\n'? The code mixes such an array (almost) with a linked list version, too... What is your desired result after loading the text file?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, first of all I do not agree that `fread` can only be used to read binary data, it is written in the documentation that you can specify the type of data with the appropriate options to `fopen` and I found many examples at the time I wrote this code that illustrate how to use `fread` to read text data ... If you have better doc please share it I would really appreciate that.

Comment: Now what I really want after reading the file is a buffer that contains null terminated strings, and another one that contains pointers to the beginning of each of these strings, and that would be the beginning of each lines.

Comment: I noticed that part of the code was probably not as clear as I thought it was, so I edited it and inserted missing information, @Fe2O3 if you could help me understand if there is still a memory leak and why I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Just read the EDIT to this question. Valiant try to chop the lines into a linked list, and then transfer those into an array of pointers... Please read and consider my posted answer... This "bulk loads" the file, then builds the array of pointers to "lines" directly...

Comment: So. "caused by a typo"... This question should be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved using the `b` option with the `fopen` function:

```
coordf = fopen (filename, "rb");
```

After that `fread` behaves properly.

Note that in my first attempts I likely used the following and wrong order of parameters:

```
coordf = fopen (filename, "br");
```

That does not work.

Answer (score 0):

SO is not a free code writing service. However, you've shown real effort trying to work this out for yourself. Point-by-point correction would take forever, so here is a "code dump" that should be easy to follow and does (I hope) what you've tried hard to achieve.

This is in "plain, ordinary" C, without the "gXXXX" functions shown in your code. This opens & loads an entire (presumed-to-be) text file, squishes out CR if present, then slices the lines assigning pointers into a growing array of pointers to each line. (Empty lines will be assigned a pointer, too) Some `printf` lines report on some statistics of the process.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Load file contents to alloc'd memory, return pointer to buffer (to be free'd!)
char *loadFile( char *fname ) {
    FILE *fp;
    if( ( fp = fopen( fname, "rb" ) ) == NULL )
        fprintf( stderr, "Cannot open '%s'\n", fname ), exit(1);

    fseek( fp, 0, SEEK_END );
    size_t size = ftell( fp );
    fseek( fp, 0, SEEK_SET );

    char *buf;
    if( ( buf = (char*)malloc( size + 1) ) == NULL )
        fprintf( stderr, "Malloc() failed\n" ), exit(1);

    if( fread( buf, sizeof *buf, size, fp ) != size )
        fprintf( stderr, "Read incomplete\n" ), exit(1);

    fclose( fp );

    *(buf + size) = '\0'; // set xtra byte allocated to NULL (allows str functions to work)
    return buf;
}

int main() {
    char *fname = "FOO.BAR"; // To be defined...

    char *fCont = loadFile( fname ), *d, *s;

    // crush out '\r', if any
    for( d = fCont, s = fCont; (*d = *s) != '\0'; s++ )
        d += *d != '\r';
    fprintf( stderr, "Orig %ld. Without CR %ld\n", s - fCont, d - fCont );

    char **arr = NULL;
    int lcnt = 0;
    for( char *t = fCont; ( t = strtok( t, "\n" ) ) != NULL; t = NULL ) {
        char **tmp = (char**)realloc( arr, (lcnt+1) * sizeof *tmp );
        if( tmp == NULL )
            fprintf( stderr, "realloc() failed\n" ), exit(1);
        arr = tmp;
        arr[lcnt++] = t;
    }
    fprintf( stderr, "%ld lines loaded\n", lcnt );

    // "demo" the first 5 lines
    for( int i = 0; i < 5 && i < lcnt; i++ )
        fprintf( stderr, "%d - '%s'\n", i+1, arr[i] );

    /* process from arr[0] to arr[lcnt-1] */

    free( arr );
    free( fCont );

    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps. Ball's in your court now...

Comment: Thanks for sharing this piece of code, it did help me, not really how I was expecting it, it just solve the probem using `fopen (file, rb)` option. Surprisingly it appears that I did not try it before, but that does the trick. This is certainly related to @Gerhardh comment above, if you read this @Gerhardh thanks. @Fe2O3 I also appreciate the `strtok` idea that I might use, but I am not so sure that reallocating the data is such a good idea with large files ... and as a matter of fact it is slighlty slower, just slighlty.

Comment: now if I may add a comment: SO is exactly the place to ask for this, in particular as you mentioned with such a detailed example from an open source software.

Comment: Well, it seems you know better.